# Getting inconsistent "Unable to find css" errors with Rspec + Capybara + Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, ember.js, rspec, capybara

## What's Happening

In our Rspec + Capybara + selenium (FF) test suite we're getting A LOT of inconsistent "Capybara::ElementNotFound" errors.

The problem is they only happen sometimes. Usually they won't happen locally, they'll happen on CircleCi, where I expect the machines are much beefier (and so faster)?

Also the same errors usually won't happen when the spec is run in isolation, for example by running rspec with a particular line number:42.

Bare in mind however that there is no consistency. The spec won't consistently fail.

## Our current workaround - sleep

Currently the only thing we can do is to litter the specs with 'sleeps'. We add them whenever we get an error like this and it fixes it. Sometimes we have to increase the sleep times which is making out tests very slow as you can imagine.

## What about capybara's default wait time?

Doesn't seem to be kicking in I imagine as the test usually fails under the allocated wait time (5 seconds currently)

## Some examples of failure.

Here's a common failure:

```
visit "/#/things/#{@thing.id}"
find(".expand-thing").click
```

This will frequently result in:

```
Unable to find css ".expand-thing"
```

Now, putting a sleep in between those two lines fixes it. But a sleep is too brute force. I might put a second, but the code might only need half a second.

Ideally I'd like Capybara's wait time to kick in because then it only waits as long as it needs to, and no longer.

## Final Note

I know that capybara can only do the wait thing if the selector doesn't exist on the page yet. But in the example above you'll notice I'm visiting the page and the selecting, so the element is not on the page yet, so Capybara should wait.

**What's going on?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out. SO, when looking for elements on a page you have a few methods available to you:

```
first('.some-selector')
all('.some-selector') #returns an array of course
find('.some-selector')
```

`.first` and `.all` are super useful as they let you pick from non unique elements.

HOWEVER `.first` and `.all` don't seem to auto-wait for the element to be on the page.

### The Fix

The fix then is to always use `.find()`. `.find` WILL honour the capybara wait time. Using `.find` has almost completely fixed my tests (with a few unrelated exceptions).

The **gotcha** of course is that you have to use more unique selectors as `.find` MUST only return a single element, otherwise you'll get the infamous `Capybara::Ambiguous` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ember works asynchronously.  This is why Ember generally recommends using Qunit.  They've tied in code to allow the testing to pause/resume while waiting for the asynchronous functions to return.  Your best bet would be to either attempt to duplicate the pause/resume logic that's been built up for qunit, or switch to qunit.

There is a global promise used during testing you could hook up to: `Ember.Test.lastPromise`

```
Ember.Test.lastPromise.then(function(){
  //continue
});
```

Additionally visit/click return promises, you'll need some manner of telling capybara to pause testing before the call, then resume once the promise resumes.

```
visit('foo').then(function(){
  click('.expand-thing').then(function(){
    assert('foobar');
  })
})
```

Now that I've finished ranting, I'm realizing you're not running these tests technically from inside the browser, you're having them run through selenium, which means it's not technically in the browser (unless selenium has made some change since last I used it, possible).  Either way you'll need to watch that last promise, and wait on it before you can continue, testing after an asynchronous action.

Comment: hey @kingpin2k, I appreciate your answer but I'm not sure it helps. Your code sample are in js, rspec+capybara is written in ruby. Capybara just inspects the DOM, and selenium is the browser automation driver that enables the test to run js. To answer your question, selenium actually loads up an instance of ff.

Comment: yeah, I worried about that after I posted it, hence my edit, and last paragraph.  Unfortunately selenium really sucks when it comes pages that are more than just simple html and images.  Once it comes to waiting on javascript to complete, or ajax responses, you are stuck in a state of uncertainty since you aren't in contact with the actual code.

Comment: Additionally it's really difficult for selenium to know when a single page application has rendered and is available, since generally all network requests have finished, and it's building templates client side and pushing them into the dom.  That's why the general recommendation for testing SPA is to do them in page, with something like qunit/jasmine (preferably qunit in Ember, due to it being officially supported and backed by Ember)

Comment: thanks for that. Will check out qunit but found a great rails specific jasmine tutorial. I get what you're saying about selenium, but what's weird is that all capybara cares about is whether something in the DOM has changed or not, regardless of background tasks, so it's odd that capybara is moving one and throwing these element not found exceptions.